# Mass insert into table using array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm coding with the help of the PHP framework - Laravel. This code is for uploading images to Amazon S3 and storing each image info to a MySQL table:

```
$created_at = new DateTime;
$aws_path   = 'path/to/folder';
$files      = Input::file('images');
$insert[]   = array(); #Initialize array for mass inserting into table

foreach($files as $file) {

        # Image data

        $image_id = mt_rand(1000000000,9999999999);
        $extension= $file->guessClientExtension();
        $filename = $aws_path.'/'.$image_id.".".$extension;
        $path = $file->getRealPath();

        #UPLOAD IMAGE TO AMAZON S3
        $obj = array(
            'Bucket'     => 's3.bucket.com',
            'Key'        => $filename,
            'SourceFile' => $path,
            'ACL'        => 'public-read',
        );
        AWS::get('s3')->putObject($obj);

        $insert[] = array(
            'car_id'            => $car_id,
            'image_id'          => $image_id,
            'image_extension'   => $extension,
            'is_main'           => true,
            'created_at'        => $created_at
        );
}

DB::table('images')->insert($insert); #THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
```

Now, **this code works** 100% except that **I'm not able to submit data to my table**, The $insert variable is supposed to be filled with the data of each image and then after the foreach loop ends I "insert" the data on $insert to my table called 'images'.

I'm don't get any errors, it just doesn't work. Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first element of your `$insert` array is an empty array.

Instead of doing the initialization of `$insert` like that (on line 4) :

```
$insert[] = array();
```

Try that :

```
$insert = array();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I tried both ways and didn't worked either

Comment: I just figured out the error @alfallouji you can read it in this page (I answer my own issue) but you were right too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're adding an extra array:

Try...

```
    $insert = array(
        'car_id'            => $car_id,
        'image_id'          => $image_id,
        'image_extension'   => $extension,
        'is_main'           => true,
        'created_at'        => $created_at
    );
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: Try checking you table schema and comparing it to the insert. I would get a raw working insert in direct sql for testing and afterwards converting it to laravel format

Comment: It works perfectly if I use it inside the foreach loop and without using an array for mass inserting

Comment: Sorry @Vladimir Ramik, I just figured out the error you can read it in this page (I answer my own issue) but you were right too.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that I'm an idiot (sorry for that).

My code always worked but I never realized that I was able to change pages for the table in PHPmyadmin and tought that I wasn't able to add more than 30 records, but the other records where in the other pages. So in total I had 140 records from multiple tests. 2 days wasted here people, 2 days less for my deadline. Thanks for everyone that helped you were always right.